# Copying preference pane to Library folder

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to copy a settings.prefPane file to ~/Library/PreferencePanes/. But it always fails with an error that file exists.

```
NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSError *error;
[fileMgr copyItemAtPath:[appBundle pathForResource:@"settings"
                                            ofType:@"prefPane"]
                 toPath:@"~/Library/PreferencePanes/"
                  error:&error];
```

Why does it always fail ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file already exists at your path before you do anything else:

```
success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:_yourPreferencesPanePath];
if (success) {
    return;
}
```